# Question on Expected time using survival function

Tags: probability, statistics

I am dealing with a problem that says:

> A machine requires the continual operation of two independent devices
>   in order to keep functioning. It breaks down as soon as the first
>   device stops working. The time until failure of the first device is
>   uniformly distributed between time $0$ and $1$. The second device has pdf
>   $f(t) = 2t$. Find the expected time until the machine breaks down.

I know the solution, but I am trying to understand the approach done. Which is:

$$1 - F(m) = (1-F(D_1))*(1-F(D_2))$$

where $F(m)$ is the cdf of the machine, and $D_1$ & $D_2$ are the cdf's of the respective devices.

Why do I have to start by assuming that the survival function of the machine equals the product of the survival functions of the two device? If they are independent, aren't their cdf's also independent and so they equal the cdf of the machine so I don't have to start with the survival functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time until the machine breaks down is distributed like $Z=\min(X,Y)$, where $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ and $Y$ has pdf $f(t)=2t$ for $0\leq t\leq 1$. The reason we look at the survival function is because
$$
[Z>z]=[X>z,Y>z]
$$
i.e. the minimum of $X$ and $Y$ is greater than $z$ *if and only if* both $X$ and $Y$ are greater than $z$. Thus we can use the independence assumption to conclude that
$$
S_Z(z):=P(Z>z)=P(X>z)P(Y>z)=S_X(z)S_Y(z),
$$
where $S_Z,S_X$ and $S_Y$ denotes the respective survival functions.

To boil it down: we don't *assume* that "the survival function of the machine equals the product of the survival functions of the two devices". This is a consequence of our assumptions which says 1) the machine breaks down as soon as one of the devices stops working *and* 2) that the two devices are independent.

Comment: I see. The problem would then change if the question had said that the machine would break down as soon as the second device would break down. In this case, we would find the expected life time of the second device correct?

Comment: Exactly @user139605.